# New to ckeditor; how do I actually get started on Fedora?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, fedora

I feel a lot like the person who wrote [this question;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811155/what-do-i-need-to-actually-get-started-with-emberjs) I suspect, as is all too common in the computer world, the people who wrote the `CKEditor` documentation know too much about it so they skip the FIRST actual steps... Here's where I'm coming from:

In my case, I've got a goodly handful of mostly static web pages written in HTML - genuine HTML, not java script or nodejs, etc. - and these need editing now and then. ... So, I figured I'd try one of these newfangled editors. I looked at reviews for more than a dozen, and happened to pick `CKEditor` as the one to try first.

This is a Fedora shop, for good or ill, and so a simple `dnf install` and bingo, it's installed!

So far so good, right?

Well no. There's no man page, for example, no executable, no entry in KDE's menus, ...  in fact no apparent result from the install except a little less disk space. Hmmm... OK, so I go look. I find it in:

`/usr/share/ckeditor` and other `/usr/share` directories. Hmmm... None of it looks like the obvious thing to point, say, Apache's Web Server at via an `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` entry or some such.

Hmmm... So, with none obvious and with an ever decreasing list of choices, I tried opening every single file there with my web browser; I got the content of the files displayed as raw text.

**New Data**

I forgot to include versions:

- Fedora 38 (Server with KDE added)
- ckeditor-4.22.1-1.fc38.noarch

Here are the files I tried in a browser:

```
/usr/share/web-assets/ckeditor/build-config.js
/usr/share/web-assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
/usr/share/web-assets/ckeditor/config.js
/usr/share/web-assets/ckeditor/styles.js
/usr/share/web-assets/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js
/usr/share/web-assets/ckeditor/vendor/promise.js
```

Um... I am a computer professional BUT not a professional web developer: Looks like I'm not in the target audience as what I find at the `CKEditor` web site doesn't seem to point me anywhere I need to be in anything like a short trip.... I don't have a lot of time to play around, I need an editor up in short order. If it comes close, I can hack the HTML by hand if and as necessary...

It'd be great if someone could "set me straight," please?

Comment: Hints : https://opensource.com/article/23/4/website-text-editor-ckeditor **,,,, ,,,,** https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckeditor_js_load.html

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks Knud... I THINK that's telling me I can ONLY get at it if: 1) I have to edit the web page in question to add a line loading the ckeditor.js script, and 2) I have to have configured a web server to point at the ckeditor files,and  tell the server that it's OK to serve these with the pages. Is this correct?

Comment: Don't know ckeditor. .... But with no answers in two days, I just pointed to probably relevant documentation. Finding more : Google *how to use ckeditor* .

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks again, I DO think that's along the right path. But why they couldn't provide simple directions to get the clueless started is beyond me. "You're just supposed to know this stuff" isn't a good answer! ...I'll follow up on your suggestion when I have time to get a test area together. And besides, if that's how it works, I'm more puzzled since web pages aren't normally easily set up to actually write to disk space.